# JasperReport. Is it possible to print bottom border when textfield is splitted?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

When textfield contents do not fit it is transferred to the next page and there's empty border in the table. Is it possible to print bottom border when textfield is splitted?

[image]

I marked problem place, i need to close table at the end/

Comment: Can you provide some more details. I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: possible to attach a screenshot ??

Comment: post your jrxml code and screen shot.